# Virtualized table scroll on window like a normal table

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-table

I am currently trying to integrated a virtualized table in react using react–virtualized, however the table does not seem to render correctly and I am trying to understand as to why. I also have a few other problems that I cant find documentation on how to do as I have pointed out below.

It would be great if anyone has something or could help.

Below is the code I am using and my goal with this is to be able to:

1- Scroll with the page the table

2- Height of rows be automatic and widths

3- The numbers shown in the row need to be formatted some depending on condition and same for wealth depending on condition may show red or green using css.

Now I have been able to get scroll to partially work however at the top of the scroll it shows massive white space when I scroll down while the table is still in view.

```
<WindowScroller>
   {({ height, isScrolling, onChildScroll, scrollTop }) => (

      <Table
        width={1000}
        autoHeight
        height={height}
        headerHeight={30}
        rowHeight={40}
        scrollTop={scrollTop}
        isScrolling={isScrolling}
        onScroll={onChildScroll}
        rowCount={this.setData.length}
        rowGetter={({index}) => this.setData[index]}>

        <Column label="Country" dataKey="country"  />
        <Column label="Flag" dataKey="flag" />
        <Column label="Population" dataKey="population" />
        <Column label="Wealth" dataKey="wealth" />

     </Table>

  )}
</WindowScroller>
```

Also just out of curiosity is there any library or way that you can just render content on scrolling eg infinite loading on scrolling down the screen that way it renders everything out of the screen as it comes in or as its about 200px from coming into view ?

Comment: I guess everyone is a lost as me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Material-UI tables for a customizable table, it's very easy and flexible.

If you prefer to use a specific table please share code.

Comment: It seems that you need a fully customizable table that also does most of the work for you. 
so Material UI it's my best recommendation library for you in general...

Comment: Material UI is not great its very limited it also uses the same library I used for virtualisation so its no help.

Comment: I guess everyone as clueless as me.